# Minify and Bundle NodeJS Project

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Haven't found much information on this topic.

Is there any tooling (gulp) for minifying and bundling a nodejs server project including its node_module dependencies?

I have a scenario where I cannot run `npm install` on the production machine and I am limited to a maximum 20 MB "executable" size.

Comment: Trying browserify | uglify. Not optimal but might do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look into the [shrinkwrap](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/) options as well as the [shrinkpack](https://github.com/JamieMason/shrinkpack) utility. It basically allows you to freeze your dependencies' versions, GZips your node modules and makes them easily deployable. You might not need Gulp for that, and Gzipping your packages is a lot more effective than uglifying it.

Comment: Compressing is not efficient enough. There are a lot of dead code in e.g. pouchdb.

Comment: Darn,... if compressing won't work, I guess minifying it won't work either :-/ Gzipping usually compresses it to 40-50% of its original size, minifying to 20-30%. You probably need both.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing pkg using npm

Steps are -

1. npm install -g pkg
2. Create a bin.js file.
         write a code that points to the main.js file/ or file which is the starting one

   ```
      const mainCode = require('.')
   ```
3. Simply add a property "bin" with value "bin.js" to your package json like so:

   ```
      {
         "name": "mainCode",
         "version": "1.0.0",
         "description": "web server app",
         "main": "main.js",
         "bin": "bin.js", 
         "author": "anybody",
         "license": "MIT"
       }
   ```
4. Then run command from the project folder path

   ```
       pkg -t node10-win .
   ```

So, FYI  -t is the target that tells for which os the executable has to be generated ( You can check pkg --help for more info)

and node10 is the version ( actually node11 is not supported but you can check others on this link below )

https://github.com/zeit/pkg-fetch/releases

Comment: what do we do with the generated file though