# How to combine multiple javascript files to 1 file using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Hallo everyone**,

I have created a big JavaScript Projekt with more than 10 js files. Now I want to combine the codes of all js files in 1 file. I have created a test file with node.js, but it does nothing and i dont know what the Problem is.

```js
var fs = require("fs");

var codes = ["M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/combineFunc/file1.js","M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/combineFunc/file2.js","M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/combineFunc/file3.js"];

var combined = "";

for(let x = 0; x < codes.length; x++) {
 fs.readFile(codes[x], "UTF-8", function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
   throw err;
  }
        combined += data;
 });
}
fs.writeFile('M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/combineFunc/ugly.js', combined , function(err) {
 if(err) {
  return console.log(err);
 }
 
 console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

If you have an Idee, how to solve this Problem, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minify and Bundle NodeJS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049923/minify-and-bundle-nodejs-project)

Comment: I dont want to minify my scripts. I only want to write the code from all js files in 1 single other file. The new file shoud indlude all variables and functions from all other files combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a way to solve my Problem by my self**,

```
    var fs = require("fs");

const codes = ["M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaVar.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaSocket.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaChat.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaVarMain.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaField.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaFriends.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaArchive.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaMain.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaTimer.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaActions.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaFight.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaKeys.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaLvUp.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaMarket.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaMove.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaNextPl.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaParaUp.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaSoul.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaGetFunc.js",
    "M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/original_Codes/chaStart.js"];


function readIt() {
    let combined = [];
    let doneCheck = [];
    let errVal = false;
    for (let x = 0; x < codes.length; x++) {
        doneCheck.push(false);
    }
    for (let x = 0; x < codes.length; x++) {
        fs.readFile(codes[x], "UTF-8", function (err, data) {
            if (err || !data) {
                console.log(codes[x]);
            } else {
                combined.push(data);
                doneCheck[x] = true;
            }
            if (x == (codes.length - 1)) {
                saveIt(combined, doneCheck);
            }
        });
    }
}
function saveIt(combined, doneCheck, round = 0) {
    let counter = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < doneCheck.length; x++) {
        if (doneCheck[x] == false) {
            fs.readFile(codes[x], "UTF-8", function (err, data) {
                if (err || !data) {
                    console.log(codes[x]);
                } else {
                    combined.push(data);
                    doneCheck[x] = true;
                }
                if (x == (codes.length - 1)) {
                    return saveIt(combined, doneCheck, round);
                }
            });
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter < doneCheck.length) {
        return false;
    }
    let combined_string = "";
    for (let y = 0; y < combined.length; y++) {
        combined_string = combined_string + combined[y] + " ";
    }
    fs.writeFile('M:/HTML-Projekte/ChabanicSouls/ugly.js', combined_string, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return readIt();
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
}

readIt();
```

This way works perfectly :-)